# Why are DEBUG messages omitted despite a .setLevel(logging.DEBUG)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

This must be something obvious but the following code does not log as expected:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('hello')
log.debug('debug one')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.debug('debug two')
log.critical('critical one')
```

I expected to get `debug two` and `critical one` but get only `critical one`. Isn't the [`.setLevel()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) I used supposed to decrease the logging level from the default `INFO`?

Comment: There are **two** filtering opportunities: in the logger (limiting propagation), and in the handlers (deciding what is actually recorded in that handler, you can have multiple handlers). You only configured the logger, not the handler(s). See the duplicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: thank you. What I get from the linked question and the docs (specifically *[a handler] is not set, [the logging functions] will set a destination of the console (`sys.stderr`)*) is that I **have to** set up a handler if I want to send messages above `WARNING` because `setLevel()` will let messages flow to the handler, but a default handler is not set up (and therefore cannot be configured with a lower logging level).